# jQuery Promises with chained setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a little dice game to learn.
What I do is i scrumble the dice X amount of times, keep slowing the random down until it gets to the final value, and that's the "winning number".

But i would like to execute the scrumble 1 by 1 on the dices. Imagine I got 2. And later I do a little zoom effect.
I was thinking I could achieve this by using promises but is not working for me, I don't know what I'm missing.

Here's the JS code:

```
var counter = 0.8;
var diceNumber = 0;

var rollDice = function(diceId){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    $('#' + diceId).removeClass('idle');

    counter *= 1.2;

    diceNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*5) + 1;

    $('#' + diceId).removeClass();
    $('#' + diceId).addClass('dice_' + diceNumber);

    if(counter < 800) {
        timeout = setTimeout(rollDice, counter, diceId);
    }else{
        $('.winner').text(diceNumber);
        $('#' + diceId).removeClass();
        $('#' + diceId).addClass('animate');
        $('#' + diceId).addClass('dice_' + diceNumber)
        .animate({ zoom: '1.3' }, 200)
        .animate({ zoom: '1' }, 100);

        dfd.resolve();

        return dfd.promise();
    } 
}


var startToDice = function() {
    rollDice('dice_1').then(rollDice('dice_2'));
}

startToDice();
```

And what it ends up doing is running both dices simultaneously.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Only your `else` branch returns a promise?

Comment: That promise is always resolved synchronously?

Comment: `then` expects a callback function, not the result of a call!

Comment: Yes, that else would mean the dice finished rolling sort of speak.. that's why i would like to return the resolve there... yea i know what you're talking about, i should return a promise in the function not only in the else, right?

Comment: yes, it should be resolved synchronously... it won't go away until it finishes and then i want it to go to the next dice.

Comment: If the promise you return is _always_ resolved, before you return it, what's the point of using a promise?

Comment: I want to chain the dices 1 by 1.. is there any other cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. I couldn't test cause I don't have all the elements in place, but try this out:

```
var counter = 0.8;
var diceNumber = 0;

var rollDice = function(diceId){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    var roll = function() {
        $('#' + diceId).removeClass('idle');

        counter *= 1.2;

        diceNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*5) + 1;

        $('#' + diceId).removeClass();
        $('#' + diceId).addClass('dice_' + diceNumber);

        if(counter < 800) {
            timeout = setTimeout(roll, counter);
        }else{
            $('.winner').text(diceNumber);
            $('#' + diceId).removeClass();
            $('#' + diceId).addClass('animate');
            $('#' + diceId).addClass('dice_' + diceNumber)
            .animate({ zoom: '1.3' }, 200)
            .animate({ zoom: '1' }, 100);

            dfd.resolve();
        } 
    }

    roll();

    return dfd.promise();
}


var startToDice = function() {
    rollDice('dice_1').then(function(){
         rollDice('dice_2');
    });
}

startToDice();
```

Let me know if you get any errors when you run it so I can make adjustments as necessary.

Comment: Nice approach. But still didn't work, don't know why, because what you did makes sense to me. And no errors on console.

Comment: @msqar Well what's happening now? I'm pretty sure you're not getting the `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'` error anymore, so what's the next step? :)

Comment: Yes, i'm not getting that error anymore, because atm i'm returning the promise from the outter function (rollDice). The structure is way better now, but the second dice isn't starting rolling. You know why?

Comment: Oh that's weird, i see what you say. Let me check.

Comment: I know what it was lol :) it was the count not being reset before resolving promise! Thanks man!

Comment: @msqar Glad you got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Like comented by bergi:

```
var startToDice = function() {
    rollDice('dice_1').then(function() { rollDice('dice_2'); });
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping. Thing is, with my current code, if i do that. I get an error on console saying 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' because i'm only returning a promise within the else. Looks like my current structure of the function might be incorrect.

Comment: Mmmm not quite sure, i'm passing all the parameters by now.